# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) // Werkzeug Debugger

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to get all the titles from a a table
but I keep getting this error:

```
builtins.ValueError
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

my code:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT title from cards")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply return a list, you have to return something that Flask knows how to interpret as an HTTP response. Here's an example from [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/views/#show-entries):

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

Exactly what you should return depends on your use case. If you want to return a JSON response, consider [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.json.jsonify).

Comment: it works with : `cursor.fetchone()` , but i want to fetch all titles not just one

Comment: @FidelCastro do you want something human readable to display to the user? If so, render an HTML template.